# What is being in a state of being subdued called?

Tags: word-choice

> In geology, subduction is the process that takes place at convergent boundaries by which one tectonic plate moves under another tectonic plate... ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subduction))

Now I understand that quite literally, subduction is a process whereby one thing goes underneath another; and while figuratively an emotional state being subdued by another state or a more pressing need as enforced by the superego might be considered a careful use of literary license, I would like to know if there is a less grandiose word for this state.

How can I describe the mind state of when one emotion is subdued, perhaps subverted, by another? In particular, this is in reference to the state where one wants to become aggressive, but ends up despondent because the vulnerability of aggression subverts its exercise.

Comment: I have no doubt psychologists have defined and adopted a term for this. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Kris if there is a term for this please let me know, that would obviously be an acceptable answer. As this is a question about word-choice ultimately, and not about diagnostics I would assert that your off-topic vote is ill-placed. Do not be misled by the emotional/psychological content; insofar as this could also be answered by subduction, this is not a question for geologists.

Comment: Neither of us could be said to be qualified to do so, I'm neither into geology nor psycology. You are expected to ask on a relevant SE for an authoritative/ reliable answer and not speculate. You can migrate the Q. for a better and qualified response. I do that myself all the time.

Comment: @Jasper Loy How do we suggest an answer without understanding its implications? DSL Qs are best dealt with on respective sites, aren't they?

Comment: I don't get it. The verb of subduction is *subduct*, not *subdue*. Subduction speaks of one thing putting itself under another; subduing speaks of one thing putting another under itself.

Comment: See the pitfalls! There are nuances.

Comment: @zpletan *subduction* was a red herring. Which is the reason I advised migrating.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for the concern, but I am not looking for a technical answer; I think that subduction makes for a nice metaphor of the state, and to use psychological terms too easily betrays my lack of knowledge of the subject. This question is about describing a mind state, and how to use literary license. The authority to whom I submit is that of English usage rather than sciences whose words I don't mean to co-opt unless a concept (e.g. coping mechanism) is sufficiently broad or a word (e.g. suppression) captures the pressure of two competing emotional needs.

Comment: @zpletan Please note, this is not a single-word-request or substitution; I used subduction and subdued as descriptors of being in a state of being subdued, the former applies overly literally to the process, the latter to the emotional transition

Comment: There is undoubtedly a proper clinical term for this, and a subject matter expert is in a better position to respond. Terms like "repression" and "suppression" come to mind, but these mean something very specific in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *[sublimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_%28psychology%29)* is related:

> In psychology, sublimation is a mature type of defence mechanism where socially unacceptable impulses or idealizations are consciously transformed into socially acceptable actions or behaviour, possibly converting the initial impulse in the long term.
>   ... The substitution might not be quite what we want, but it is the only way that we can get part of our satisfaction and feel secure, too.

As suggested in a comment, to "be in a state of sublimation" is of questionable form.  Yes, one may experience sublimation, and one may say an emotion was sublimated.

More generally, sublimation might be a *[defense mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_mechanism)*.

> In Freudian psychoanalytic theory, ... defense mechanisms are unconscious psychological strategies brought into play by various entities to cope with reality and to maintain self-image

Or it might be a *[coping strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coping_strategy)*:

> Coping is ... expending conscious effort to solve personal and interpersonal problems, and seeking to master, minimize or tolerate stress or conflict. Psychological coping mechanisms are commonly termed coping strategies or coping skills. Unconscious or non conscious strategies (e.g., defense mechanisms) are generally excluded.

Comment: Does one 'be in a state of sublimation'? Or one experiences a process of sublimation?

Comment: @Kris - see edit

Answer (score 2):

You may speak of the *suppression* of emotions.

Comment: Thank you. I was just waiting for you to give me the go-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a technical answer, as you say in your comment, then an alternative to suppressed would be **muted**, meaning reduced in intensity (or silenced, metaphorically).